# Cannot get Russian Subject from Outlook using RDCOMClient

Tags: r, rdcomclient

I am using Outlook under Windows 10 as my email client and am trying to use the RDCOMClient library to process some emails. Some of the emails are in Russian and I am having trouble getting the Russian part out in a usable format. Right now, I am just 
focusing on the subject lines. When I extract the line and print 
it out,  I just get question marks except for a few Latin characters
in the subject. I have tried setting the encoding and using 
iconv, but with no success. But iconv did provide a useful clue. 
Based on my reproducible example below showing the raw characters 
gives:

```
iconv(SUBJECT, toRaw=T)
 [1] 53 74 61 63 6b 4f 76 65 72 66 6c 6f 77 54 65 73 74 4d 65 73 73 61 67 65 3a
[26] 20 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 20 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f
```

All of the 3f's at the end? That is the code for question mark. RDCOMClient is 
actually returning the ??? from Outlook. It is not some encoding issue inside R.

I have looked at many RDCOMClient posts on SO, but do not see anything 
that deals with this problem.

Is the RDCOMClient<->Outlook connection just broken? Or is there some way
around this?

**Attempt at Reproducible Example**

Since we are talking about accessing email, I don't see how to make a 
really easy reproducible example, but here is a reproducible way to test this.
Of course, you have to have Outlook on Windows for this to make sense.

1. Send yourself an email with the subject line:
   StackOverflowTestMessage: Тестовое сообщение
2. R code
   We need to find the email first. Most of the code does that. 
   Then we inspect the subject.

````
## Connect to Outlook
OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
outlookNameSpace = OutApp$GetNameSpace("MAPI")

## Find the Inbox
INBOX = outlookNameSpace$GetDefaultFolder(6)
INBOX$Name()            ## Confirm
emails <- INBOX$Items

## Find the relevant email
NumEmail = emails()$Count()
MessageNumber = 0
for(i in NumEmail:1) {
    SUBJ = emails(i)$Subject()
    if(grepl("StackOverflowTestMessage", SUBJ)) {
        MessageNumber = i
        break()
    }
}

## Now try to get the subject line
SUBJECT = emails(MessageNumber)$Subject()
Encoding(SUBJECT) = 'UTF-8'
SUBJECT
[1] "StackOverflowTestMessage: ???????? ?????????"
iconv(SUBJECT, toRaw=T)
[[1]]
 [1] 53 74 61 63 6b 4f 76 65 72 66 6c 6f 77 54 65 73 74 4d 65 73 73 61 67 65 3a
[26] 20 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 20 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f```
````

Comment: Do you get the same results if other programming languages or packages are used? Is the issue specific to the RDCOMClient?

Comment: This is specific to RDComClient.  However, I also tried using perl with Win32::OLE. and had a completely different set of problems.  This question is for R.  I would be open to solutions using other R packages.

Comment: So, it is not related to Outlook.

Comment: Incorrect.  I specifically want to get my email out of Outlook  - using R to automate the process.The question is about an interaction between R and Outlook.

Comment: The Outlook object model is common for all kinds of applications. If you see the same issue in other programming languages then it is a problem of Outlook. If you don't get same issue then the problem is in R (or frameworks you are using).